# How can I resolve a Mockito argument matching problem?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I'm testing a `dao` in the android app. I'm using **mockito** for unit test, after creating a mock `dao` when I do `when` on  `dao.insert(CustomerClass)` I have the below error:

> when(java.lang.void)in mockito cannot be applied to(void).

```
@Dao
public interface WListDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from wlist_table ORDER BY title ASC")
    LiveData<List<WList>> getAllWList();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(WList wList);

    @Delete
    void delete(WList wList);

}
```

//////////////////////

```
@Test
    public void addNewWListToDb(){
        WListDao dao = mock(WListDao.class);
        int count =0;
        when(dao.insert(any(WList.class))).thenAnswer(count++);
    }
```

Comment: Updated the sentence and code format applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax:

```
when(mockObject.someMethod(someParameter)).thenAnswer(someAnswer);
```

...isn't valid for void methods.  Instead, you have to use this syntax:

```
doAnswer(someAnswer).when(mockObject).someMethod(someParameter);
```

Pay special attention to the paren placements.  For the `doAnswer` syntax, the method invocation goes *outside* of the when's parens.

See the Mockito documentation [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#do_family_methods_stubs) for more info.